# echo output is different on linux and windows OSes

Tags: linux, windows, unix, cmd, command

My example command line is:

```
echo I\'m X.
```

When I run this from linux OS, output is `I'm X.`

But windows OS output is `I\'m X.`

I want to get output as linux in windows. Is it possible or not ?

Why this error happened?

Comment: The terminal differs and shell differs. Look for https://www.cygwin.com/ if you want linux-like shell in windows.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows you can do that without quoting:

```
echo I'm X.
```

Obviously every system has their own shell/terminal interface so some would evaluate strings or arguments differently from another.

You'll find that shells like `sh` and those derived from it easier to work with when it comes to variable expansions and string manipulations than with `command.com` or `cmd.exe`.